# How do I configure Exchange to relay unknown email addresses in the accepted domain

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

Exchange is set up to receive *@company.com emails and will reject any incoming mail to a mailbox that is not recognized.

How to I tell Exchange to instead relay those emails to another mailserver (not and Exchange server)?

Comment: As the setting "forward all mail with unresolved recipients" is now longer usable, you need a tip like show there https://telnet25.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/internal-relay-domain-forward-all-mail-with-unresolved-recipients-to-host/ If that work, let me know as will write it as an answer.

Comment: You need to create an internal relay accepted domain.

Comment: @yagmoth555 that looks promising — I will report back whether it works, thanks